# Can I get to source code from Crash Signature (windows crash report)

Tags: c++, debugging, windows-7, crash, crash-reports

By crash Signature I mean 'Problem Signature' but stackoverflow doesn't allow 'problem' word in title.

My applications crashes randomly which results in a typical Windows 7 crash dialog. You press the show problem details button and it shows 'problem signature' which looks something like this:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:       APPCRASH
  Application Name:         MyAPP.exe
  Application Version:      1.0.0.1
  Application Timestamp:    56f42d87
  Fault Module Name:        KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version:     6.1.7601.23392
  Fault Module Timestamp:   524f83ff
  Exception Code:           e06d7363
  Exception Offset:         000084d5
  OS Version:               6.1.7600.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:                1033
  Additional Information 1: 59d3
  Additional Information 2: 59d2b19b48819489f0f177fd879bb2a4
  Additional Information 3: 4230
  Additional Information 4: 4230b7cc692f7b01f72cd61a9ca3153f
```

I see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oanapl/2009/01/30/windows-error-reporting-and-clr-integration/) what it means but can I use this information to get to the source code and preferably the line number which is causing the crash?

Comment: The link you provide tells you what you need to know.

Comment: @CrazyEddie I only have numbers, I don't how it shows text as well in additional information. I don't see what I can do from there.

Comment: Hmm...that's unfortunate because it spells out in detail how to get the information you need.

Comment: does it work? Were you able to generate dumps and analyze them in windbg?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that what you want is a minidump (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680369(v=vs.85).aspx). That would likely provide you the info you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Configure the Windows Error Reporting (WER)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638(VS.85).aspx) to generate a dumps (works since `Windows Server 2008 RTM/Vista Sp1`). This sample .reg file configures Windows to create full memory dumps of all app crashes and stores them into `C:\localdumps`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps]
"DumpFolder"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,4c,00,6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,44,00,75,\
  00,6d,00,70,00,73,00,00,00
"DumpType"=dword:00000002
```

If you only want to get dumps of your app, import this .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\MyAPP.exe]
"DumpFolder"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,4c,00,6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,44,00,75,\
  00,6d,00,70,00,73,00,00,00
"DumpType"=dword:00000002
```

Change the MyAPP.exe to your real application name.

Now open the dmp in Windbg, configure the [Microsoft symbols server  access in Windbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552208(v=vs.85).aspx) and also add your private PDBs to the symbol search path. Now run `.srcfix; !analyze -v` and look what Windbg tells you where you application crashed.

Comment: Thanks I was able to generate the dump file but only via task manager. I don't have any registry entries so I guess defaults should work? It does generate dump file for a simple demp app automatically but doesn't for the real application. Don't know why that is. I haven't tried your reg file but does it really need to be filled? The default values of registry wouldn't work?

Comment: for me it works. Some AV suites block access. You can configure the values on your own with regedit.exe. you can also use procdump t register it as post mortem debugger: **procdump -ma -i C:\localdumps**

Comment: Thanks it turn out it was created but not in default folder but elsewhere because of previous configuration. I am following up on analysis to make pdf files work.

Comment: is your question now answered? Do you need to know more?